# Sequential thread execution to print 1A 2B 3C 4D

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, atomic

I have implemented two threads, one to print integers and other one to print English alphabets. The threads are supposed to work in tandem.

I use a synchronized block and only one thread will hold the lock at a time. But somehow, the AtomicInteger is not working as expected. The changes to count variable made by one thread is not visible to other different thread. How's this possible. Am i missing something?

**My Implementation**

```
package com.concurrency;
```

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class ThreadWaitEg 
{

```
// Single monitor object for both threads
private final Object monitor = new Object();
// Thread-safe counter for both threads
private final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

private class PrintNumber implements Runnable 
{

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) 
        {
            synchronized (monitor) 
            {
                System.out.println("From PrintNumber "+count.get());
                try 
                {
                    while ((count.get()) % 2 != 0) 
                    {
                        monitor.wait();
                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(i);
                count.getAndIncrement();
                monitor.notifyAll();

            }
        }

    }

}

private class PrintChar implements Runnable 
{

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {

        for (int charr = 'A'; charr <= 'Z'; charr++) 
        {
            synchronized (monitor) 
            {
                System.out.println("From PrintChar "+count.get());
                try 
                {
                    while ((count.get()) % 2 == 0) 
                    {
                        monitor.wait();
                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println((char) charr);
                count.getAndIncrement();
                monitor.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("from main thread");
    Runnable runInt = new ThreadWaitEg().new PrintNumber();
    new Thread(runInt).start();
    Runnable runChar = new ThreadWaitEg().new PrintChar();
    new Thread(runChar).start();
    System.out.println(" main thread completes ");
}
```

}

**Output**

from main thread
From PrintNumber 0
0
From PrintNumber 1
 main thread completes
From PrintChar 0

Comment: Not the actual problem, but one of your loops will iterate 25 times, the other 26.

Comment: @AndyTurner: I made changes to the class and now both loops will iterate 26 times.

Comment: You acquire a mutex on `monitor` and then, whilst holding it, wait for another thread which also wants the mutex on `monitor` to notify the first thread. I'm guessing you've got a deadlock.

Comment: It's OK to hold the mutex on an object, and whilst holding it, calling monitor.wait(), as this will relinquish the lock and go to BLOCKING state waiting for the signal from other thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you create two instances of the main ThreadWaitEg class - each with its own copy of the "monitor" and "count" objects, thus the objects are not shared between the two threads. The quickest fix is to create just a single instance, i.e. replace you main() method with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("from main thread");
    ThreadWaitEg threadWaitEg = new ThreadWaitEg();
    Runnable runInt = threadWaitEg.new PrintNumber();
    new Thread(runInt).start();
    Runnable runChar = threadWaitEg.new PrintChar();
    new Thread(runChar).start();
    System.out.println(" main thread completes ");
}
```